# Gnome-clocks folder/file

Tags: gnome

I have five computers in my house and I wanted to set Gnome-clocks with/from the master, having set the clock with 9 different cities I cannot seem to find the file/folder to copy and install into the other 4 computers

Hoping someone can help, would be very much appreciated

Hazz

Answer (score 4):

The locations added to the clock are not stored in a simple file or folder that you can copy to other computers. The settings are stored in a binary database file similar to the registry on Windows. You instead will need to use the `dconf dump` and `dconf load` commands, to export and import the settings on the other computers, respectively.

On the computer with the existing settings, run:

`dconf dump /org/gnome/clocks/ > gnome-clocks.dconf`

Then copy the `gnome-clocks.dconf` file to the other computers, and run this command on them:

`cat gnome-clocks.dconf | dconf load /org/gnome/clocks/`

Comment: Perfect... We can backup data as well. let me put this code to my backup script. I will help me to restore configs... :)